# Has anyone started a port of the Textmate tmbundle for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, textmatebundles

I loved this bundle in Rails 2

```
https://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle
```

But now that I'm moving to Rails 3, I'm feeling left out in the cold.

Should I just start my own branch and upgrade the tools as they're broken, or has somebody started on this in the past year?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not kind of answer you expect but try [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) - it's just awesome for development with rails, especially rails 3. I know also it is paid software, but then just calculate your time versus cost of license.

Comment: Yeah, a non-answer, but I do appreciate the referral. I'd been a Textmate fan for a while, but then I *really* became a fan when I started doing Rails 2.3* about 6 months ago. Now that my company is ready to start some Rails 3 projects, there's a lot less support on the frontier.

Comment: for what I understood from one of interviews with drnic text mate is a good editor, but nothing more. So I think he will not work on improving tmbundle when there are as good tools as RubyMine is. And if your company is doing rails development ask them to buy you RubyMine license or buy one for yourself (Personal license), it is cheaper and gives you right to code rails on all the machines you work with - actually I got one after Sun terminated support for rails in Netbeans - and it really works.

Comment: http://thechangelog.com/post/3581880961/episode-0-5-0-ruby-rails-and-the-cloud-with-dr-nic-from - here is the interview